# Image resize is not working correctly

Tags: jquery

So i have this function which should resize some huge sized images that are being loaded with ajax when a person clicks on a certain link. So basically i have a side bar with a list of users and once you click on one user in the right side of the screen you should get all info about him with a picture that should be proportionally resized to 250 width. And what happens in my case is that sometimes when it loads the height of is not correct, its much less then it should be and when i click on the user again (to load it again) it loads in with correct height.

This is my function for resizing

```
function resizeImage()
            {
                $(function() {
                    var max_size = 250;
                    $(".asd img").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
                            var h = max_size;
                            var w = Math.ceil($(this).width() / $(this).height() * max_size);
                        }
                        else {
                            var w = max_size;
                            var h = Math.ceil($(this).height() / $(this).width() * max_size);
                        }
                        $(this).css({'height': h, 'width': w});
                    });
                });
            }
```

I call this function after the content from ajax is called

```
$(document).on('click', '.search-resultb', function(e) {
                $('.tab-content').html('<img style="margin:200px 0px 0px 330px;" src="img/ajax-loader.gif"><br> <span style="margin:200px 0px 0px 320px;">Ucitavanje...</span>');
                $.post("search.php", {
                    mode: 2,
                    id: $(this).attr("data-plan-id"),
                    postPlan: $(this).text(),
                    postUser_level: <?php echo $ks->user_level ?>
                }, function(response) {

                    $('#pregled').html(response);
                     resizeImage();
                });
            });
```

if i didn't explain something please ask i really need help with this.

Comment: I believe you can accomplish what you want simply with CSS, by adding `max-width:250px;` to the CSS for the image, or maybe simply `width:250px;`. No js needed...

Comment: If you have an image tag and you specify the Width as "250" the height will auto-scale to match the proportions, like Ted suggested. You can do that using jQuery to add the style attribute or by setting the width directly on the image tag.

Comment: i didn't know that this would proportionally resize the image. Thank you guys.